# Yandex карты в Webview React Native android

Tags: android, css, yandex-maps-api, webview

Проблема с отображением карты в webview React Native. Webview растянута на весь экран, но при запуске высота карт 8px.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init () {
        new ymaps.Map('map', {
                    center:[52.076015,23.723014],
                    zoom:10
                },
                {
                    suppressMapOpenBlock: true
                });
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    html{
        min-height:100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    body{
        height:100%;
    }
    #map{
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

В Chrom'e отображение корректное, осталось понять, почему в браузере в приложении оно ведет себя иначе.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали задать ширину-высоту карты через vw и vh?

```
#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```